# SAPUI5 Web-Application: VizFrame (stacked column) show sum of measures (y-Axis)

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, hana

Currently, I am working on a web application (html5, sapui5) that visualizes customer data.

For now we had a simple model that basically shows you how many items were repaired/sent back unrepaired etc. So, it looks like that in SAP HANA:

month - year - repaired - unrepaired

---

1     - 2014 - 12       - 15

2    -   2014  -  10   -     12

---

VizFrame visualizes that data as a stacked column just fine.

Now we have to add a new filter (for now it's filtering the years) that is supposed to be applied to an item category. So, the tables in SAP HANA will look like this:

month - year - repaired - unrepaired - item category

1  -     2014  -  2  -         3     -     CategoryA

1 -      2014 -   4       -    6      -    CategoryB

1 -      2014 -   2     -      1   -       CategoryC

1     -  2014   - 5       -    5      -    CategoryD

1   -    2014  -  2  -         3      -    CategoryE

The data is being displayed as "Month/Year", so for every month there's a stacked column per year displaying the values. It works just fine as well.

The problem is: Instead of showing 15 items repaired for Jan/2014 when no filter is applied, it only visualizes the very first row.

Is there a way to aggregate/sum those values when defining the column chart? The definition was done in Javascript.

Thanks :)

PS.: I'm sorry the table "examples" may look weird (as I see in the question preview), I just wanted to explain the basic data structure

Comment: Are you using HANA XS ? If yes, you could define aggregations in the XSOdata definition.

Comment: I think this will not work when you just have Month and Year as dimension. You can add "Category" as dimension or create an aggregated view as Stephen suggested. Then you can implement a drill down.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I did add Category as a dimension but mentioned in the "data" property the following: "data" : parameters : {select : 'Month', 'Year'} so the category was still a dimension but only in the "background" :) Since the numbers were correct, I think it worked.